# Kotlin NexusDeploy task failing since upgrading to 1.8.20

Tags: kotlin, gradle, github-actions

I have this snippet in my `build.gradle` executing using a GitHub Action and it was previously working with Kotlin 1.8.0.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.20'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'checkstyle'
}

group = 'com.my-group'
version = '1.0.29'

...

publishing {
    publications {
        NexusDeploy(MavenPublication) {
            artifact("./build/libs/my-jar.jar") {
                extension 'jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since upgrading to Kotlin 1.8.20, the publish fails with the following message:

```
> Failed to publish publication 'NexusDeploy' to repository 'Nexus'
   > Invalid publication 'NexusDeploy': artifact file does not exist: '/home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/my-project/my-project/build/libs/my-jar.jar'
```

Nothing has changed in the `build.gradle` aside from the version of Kotlin.

I read through the [Kotlin 1.8.20 changelog](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1820.html), but nothing stood out to me as a source of the problem.

Building the `.jar` locally puts it in the same place it was before, so I'm not sure why the GHA is unable to find it.

Clearly something has changed about how Kotlin handles building artifacts, but I don't have a clue what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to simplify the publishing block.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        NexusDeploy(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```